# Optional SPNEGO Kerberos authentication

Tags: kerberos, spnego

Is it possible to do optional kerberos authentication?

What I want is: if the client (browser) is not on the domain it is redirected to a username/password web login. Otherwise it will do SPNEGO do Kerberos authentication.

If I just send the WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate header to a non domain browser it just does nothing further.

Is there some option to tell the browser to try something different if it doesn't know how to authenticate? Or do I have to determine if user is part of the domain before sending the "WWW-Authenticate" header?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem as the OP and I am wondering, if there is an established solution in the meantime. When the login page is accessed from outside the domain, the Kerberos process stops on the client-side after receiving the 401. Is there a way (other than the JavaScript hack descried by gra) to run these two authentication methods in parallel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't found anynone who has solved this publicly and in a standard way.  Yes, as mentioned, one could fall back to `Basic` but that doesn't work for authentication schemes which involve requesting a username and password from a CGI form where, as far as the browser sees things, you're falling back to *no* authentication if `Negotiate` fails.  Maybe that is suggestive that the authentication scheme is broken?  I don't know.

I'll tell you what I know, first.  Our site is, effectively, Cosign-protected, so we have a similar problem to you: only specially-configured machines respond to the `WWW-Authenticate` header, so by default we must send all users to our Cosign login page.  The trick is that the Cosign server also allows authenticated GSSAPI/Kerberos hosts to complete the authentication process without entering login details, but only on certain browsers, by means of a workaround.

This workaround consists simply of a block of JavaScript within the login page which attempts a `HEAD` of an SPNEGO-protected resource; if successful, the script redirects the browser to an SPNEGO-protected version of the same page, which grants appropriate Cosign cookies and completes the process without password entry.  If the browser lacks any one of JavaScript, Kerberos support or adequate credentials, then the user will see the cosign login page as usual.

So, the above alone might count as an answer to your question; personally though I don't think this goes far enough and what follows is more of a discussion...

The above seems unsatisfactory as it insists that any connecting user agent supports either JavaScript (unlikely to be the case for text-based browsers and HTTP client libraries) or knowledge of the arbitrary path to which we redirect Kerberos-capable users (useless to anything which has not been hard-coded for our site).  I've come to the conclusion that there might be a better workaround, or if not, a gap where a standard should be.  The best practical suggestion I have is this:

A normal part of the SPNEGO process is that the client attempt to retrieve a page whose initial response is an HTTP `401` but with the header `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate`.   This is the cue for a GSSAPI/Kerberised client to respond appropriately; a "regular" client will simply display the error page.  Perhaps the solution is simply to modify the Cosign server to deliver the human-friendly login page as part of this error response?

It *might* be technically difficult with off-the-shelf Apache and modules, and might go against various standards (or at least principles).  I'm no expert on the systems involved, so can only speculate unless (or until) I get a chance to try it out...

Answer (score 0):

Send additionally `WWW-Authenticate: Basic` for username/password challenge.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the application server, for example in JBoss you can set `<auth-method>SPNEGO,FORM</auth-method>` in **web.xml** and it should fall back to a login form "in cases where Kerberos/SPNEGO tokens are not present":

See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2/html/how_to_set_up_sso_with_kerberos/additional_features

Comment: That answer is wrong. You can specify exactly one `auth-method`.

Comment: Did you read the JBoss documentation page I linked?

Comment: Yes and it is wrong. Read the spec: https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-3.1/Final/servlet-3_1-final.pdf, page 14-166.

Comment: The fact it is not in the spec does not mean JBoss is prevented from doing it. If you mean to say better avoid that for compatibility reasons then it's another story, but that's different from "wrong".